# How do I repaint a form after it was restored from a minimized state?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, repaint

I have a form in which i paint a waveform on a button click that is as soon as i click button, the waveform displays. Now when i minimize the form and maximize it again, the waveform disappears.How to repaint it? I have seen people using paint event but i dont know how to use it after/inside the button click event. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you call Control.Invalidate(), the Paint event will occur.

Comment: How to use it and where? please if you can elaborate.

Comment: Windows automatically invalidates an area whenever it thinks it needs to be redrawn. It then sends notifications to the window(s) occupying that area on the screen, indicating they should re-paint the area. In .NET, this means the Paint event occurs.


By calling Invalidate() on your control, you are manually telling Windows to send these notifications to your application.

Comment: You can call Invalidate() anywhere in your code, even multiple times before the Paint event occurs. It will just mark your control as "dirty"; you don't have to worry about calling the Paint event manually.